# A dynamically content creating function using JSON is returning undefined to an outside function call in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I wanted to make a TO-DO list app for an assignment using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos. The code snippet is shown below.

```js
function generateList() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var output = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        // console.log(response[i].title);
        if (response[i].completed == true) {
          output += `<tr id='row${response[i].id}'>`;
          output += `<td><input type="checkbox" id="task${response[i].id}" checked disabled></td>`;
          output += `<td>${response[i].title}</td>`;
        } else {
          output += `<tr id='row${response[i].id}'>`;
          output += `<td><input type="checkbox" id="task${response[i].id}"></td>`;
          output += `<td>${response[i].title}</td>`;
        }
        output += "</tr>";
      }
      // document.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML = output;
      return output;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

let temp = generateList();
document.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML = temp;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Success</h1>
  <table>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="./json.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem I am facing is that, the table is not displaying. Instead it is showing `undefined`. When I used the innerHTML method inside the function instead of return statement (I have commented that statement above the return statement), it worked perfectly as I wanted. Can anyone tell me, why am I facing this error?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `xhttp.onreadystatechange` executes asynchronously and `generateList()` immediately returns `undefined` for this call:

```
let temp = generateList(); //this just returns undefined
document.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML = temp;
```

In the above call `temp` will be `undefined` since the function (`generateList`) didn't return anything (`falsy`). And then `xhttp.onreadystatechange` goes ahead with its usual asynchronous call, fetches that data and manipulates the `output`. So you can call another function **after** it's done with manipulating the `output`

Note that due to the above reason your `return output;` doesn't actually do anything.

So, this is what you can do:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var output = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        ....
        ....
        output += '...'
      }
      callFunction(output) //invoke a function with this output
      // document.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML = output;
      return output; //NOT needed
    }
```

Now you can get the output in this

```
callFunction(output){
  //here you can do anything with the output. for e.g
  document.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML = output;

}
```

You can also go ahead with `publisher` and `subscriber` architecture where after the response is received, an event will be dispatched along with `output`  and there will be a subscriber 'listening' to it which will consume this output.

Comment: Is there anyway, that I can get the actual result?

Comment: @MikhilMC see now, let me know if it's clear enough